# How to substring a given string with specific rules in java

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception, substring

This is my code and it is showing error at while.Index out of bound exception is coming.The substrings should be such that

> 1. Max 50 characters per string
> 2. No number should be broken - for example " 4318, 4466, 486," is acceptable but  " 4318, 4466, 48" is not
> 3. Substring should always start with one space and end with comma ","

can someone help me out with this please

```
 public class MyString {

/**
 * @param args

 */
static String input = " 4318, 4466, 486, 1698, 478, 590, 582, 1594, 486, 1690, 702, 378, 486, 586, 486, 1694, 486, 598, 538, 526, 486, 1694, 486, 622, 434, 630, 462, 1730, 422, 1754, 450, 586, 486, 1690, 498, 1682, 486, 586, 502, 606, 454, 1698, 478, 1694, 486, 1718, 458, 1686, 726, 1458, 646, 426, 486, 1694, 482, 1694, 486, 590, 482, 622, 490, 550, 490, 602, 450, 634, 466, 586, 486, 1730, 426, 1714, 494, 622, 446, 590, 494, 618, 450, 586, 490, 586, 486, 1730, 450, 586, 486, 590, 502, 1674, 530, 1650, 482, 1690, 558, 1622, 486, 1690, 486, 5298, 4306, 4466, 530, 1646, 486, 594, 650, 1502, 546, 1650, 490, 586, 486, 622, 522, 1622, 486, 602, 454, 634, 462, 1694, 482, 590, 486, 590, 486, 1694, 482, 1730, 450, 590, 498, 1638, 526, 1690, 498, 606, 458, 586, 486, 1698, 482, 1694, 482, 1690, 486, 1694, 486, 1698, 574, 494, 486, 1714, 462, 1690, 486, 626, 430, 610, 486, 590, 490, 622, 426, 610, 498, 618, 446, 1690, 486, 1734, 446, 590, 482, 590, 502, 606, 454, 590, 502, 582, 478, 1690, 486, 586, 506, 578, 482, 1686, 558, 1622, 674, 1506, 482, 1698, 590, 1606, 462, 1000";
char space=' ';
 static char comma=',';
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int start=0, end=0;
    while (end-1 < input.length()){

    start=end;
    end= start+ 50;

    String output= input.substring(start,end);
    if(output.charAt(start)==' ' && output.charAt(end-1)==',')
    {
    System.out.println(output);
    } 
    else 
    {

    while(!(output.charAt(end-1)==','))
    {

    end--;

    }
    output= input.substring(start,end);
    System.out.println(output);

    }
    }
    }



}
```

Comment: if end =0 the is end-1 =-1 (while (end-1 < input.length()){ ) and you get the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made slight modification in your code.

```
class Ideone {

static String input = " 4318, 4466, 486, 1698, 478, 590, 582, 1594, 486, 1690, 702, 378, 486, 586, 486, 1694, 486, 598, 538, 526, 486, 1694, 486, 622, 434, 630, 462, 1730, 422, 1754, 450, 586, 486, 1690, 498, 1682, 486, 586, 502, 606, 454, 1698, 478, 1694, 486, 1718, 458, 1686, 726, 1458, 646, 426, 486, 1694, 482, 1694, 486, 590, 482, 622, 490, 550, 490, 602, 450, 634, 466, 586, 486, 1730, 426, 1714, 494, 622, 446, 590, 494, 618, 450, 586, 490, 586, 486, 1730, 450, 586, 486, 590, 502, 1674, 530, 1650, 482, 1690, 558, 1622, 486, 1690, 486, 5298, 4306, 4466, 530, 1646, 486, 594, 650, 1502, 546, 1650, 490, 586, 486, 622, 522, 1622, 486, 602, 454, 634, 462, 1694, 482, 590, 486, 590, 486, 1694, 482, 1730, 450, 590, 498, 1638, 526, 1690, 498, 606, 458, 586, 486, 1698, 482, 1694, 482, 1690, 486, 1694, 486, 1698, 574, 494, 486, 1714, 462, 1690, 486, 626, 430, 610, 486, 590, 490, 622, 426, 610, 498, 618, 446, 1690, 486, 1734, 446, 590, 482, 590, 502, 606, 454, 590, 502, 582, 478, 1690, 486, 586, 506, 578, 482, 1686, 558, 1622, 674, 1506, 482, 1698, 590, 1606, 462, 1000";
char space = ' ';
static char comma = ',';

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (end < input.length()) {

        start = end;
        end = Math.min(start + 50, input.length());

        String output = input.substring(start, end - 1);
        if (output.charAt(0) == ' ' && output.charAt(output.length() - 1) == ',') {
            System.out.println(output);
            end--;
        } else {
            temp = output.length() - 1;
            while (temp!=-1 && output.charAt(temp) != ',') {
                temp--;
            }
            if(temp==-1)break;
            output = input.substring(start, start + temp + 1);
            System.out.println(output);
            end = start + temp + 1;
        }

    }
}
}
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/vV5uZv)**

Comment: this code is correct and it is giving the output as expected only the last number ie 1000 is not getting printed.Can you please suggest the necessary changes?

Comment: yes, it won't as per your requirement, it should only print  *Substring should always start with one space and end with comma ","* And, last one doesn't have

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the question but I think you are looking for this

```
  public class Snippet {
    static String input = " 4318, 4466, 486, 1698, 478, 590, 582, 1594, 486,            1690, 702, 378, 486, 586, 486, 1694, 486, 598, 538, 526, 486, 1694, 486, 622, 434, 630, 462, 1730, 422, 1754, 450, 586, 486, 1690, 498, 1682, 486, 586, 502, 606, 454, 1698, 478, 1694, 486, 1718, 458, 1686, 726, 1458, 646, 426, 486, 1694, 482, 1694, 486, 590, 482, 622, 490, 550, 490, 602, 450, 634, 466, 586, 486, 1730, 426, 1714, 494, 622, 446, 590, 494, 618, 450, 586, 490, 586, 486, 1730, 450, 586, 486, 590, 502, 1674, 530, 1650, 482, 1690, 558, 1622, 486, 1690, 486, 5298, 4306, 4466, 530, 1646, 486, 594, 650, 1502, 546, 1650, 490, 586, 486, 622, 522, 1622, 486, 602, 454, 634, 462, 1694, 482, 590, 486, 590, 486, 1694, 482, 1730, 450, 590, 498, 1638, 526, 1690, 498, 606, 458, 586, 486, 1698, 482, 1694, 482, 1690, 486, 1694, 486, 1698, 574, 494, 486, 1714, 462, 1690, 486, 626, 430, 610, 486, 590, 490, 622, 426, 610, 498, 618, 446, 1690, 486, 1734, 446, 590, 482, 590, 502, 606, 454, 590, 502, 582, 478, 1690, 486, 586, 506, 578, 482,   
1686, 558, 1622, 674, 1506, 482, 1698, 590, 1606, 462, 1000";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int start=0, end=0;
        String[] a=input.split(",");
        System.out.println(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(a[i]);
            if(!(a.length-1==i))
            {
            System.out.print(",");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the substrings each with maximum 50 characters and each substring should start with a space and end with a comma. And a substring like " 4318,4466," will do but not " 4318,44"

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(!(output.charAt(end-1)==','))    
{    
end--;    
}
```

change it to

```
 while(!(output.charAt(end-1)==','))
    {

  if(end>=1)
    end--;
  else
    break;

    }
```

You will not get error but you may want to change else part.
Also, you didn't ask specifically but check this link out.

[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringSplitTest
{
    static String input = " 4318, 4466, 486, 1698, 478, 590, 582, 1594, 486, 1690, 702, 378, 486, 586, 486, 1694, 486, 598, 538, 526, 486, 1694, 486, 622, 434, 630, 462, 1730, 422, 1754, 450, 586, 486, 1690, 498, 1682, 486, 586, 502, 606, 454, 1698, 478, 1694, 486, 1718, 458, 1686, 726, 1458, 646, 426, 486, 1694, 482, 1694, 486, 590, 482, 622, 490, 550, 490, 602, 450, 634, 466, 586, 486, 1730, 426, 1714, 494, 622, 446, 590, 494, 618, 450, 586, 490, 586, 486, 1730, 450, 586, 486, 590, 502, 1674, 530, 1650, 482, 1690, 558, 1622, 486, 1690, 486, 5298, 4306, 4466, 530, 1646, 486, 594, 650, 1502, 546, 1650, 490, 586, 486, 622, 522, 1622, 486, 602, 454, 634, 462, 1694, 482, 590, 486, 590, 486, 1694, 482, 1730, 450, 590, 498, 1638, 526, 1690, 498, 606, 458, 586, 486, 1698, 482, 1694, 482, 1690, 486, 1694, 486, 1698, 574, 494, 486, 1714, 462, 1690, 486, 626, 430, 610, 486, 590, 490, 622, 426, 610, 498, 618, 446, 1690, 486, 1734, 446, 590, 482, 590, 502, 606, 454, 590, 502, 582, 478, 1690, 486, 586, 506, 578, 482, 1686, 558, 1622, 674, 1506, 482, 1698, 590, 1606, 462, 1000,";
    static ArrayList chunks = new ArrayList();
    static char comma = ',';
    static String commaString = ",";
    static boolean more = true;
    static int startIndex = 0;
    static String str = null;
    static int splitIndex = 50;
    static int remainingInputLength = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while (more)
        {
            str = input.substring(startIndex, startIndex + splitIndex);
            if (str.endsWith(commaString))
            {
                startIndex += 50;
            }
            else
            {
                splitIndex = str.lastIndexOf(comma) + 1;
                str = input.substring(startIndex, startIndex + splitIndex);
                startIndex += splitIndex;
            }
            chunks.add(str);

            remainingInputLength = input.substring(startIndex).length();
            if (remainingInputLength == 0) 
            {
                more = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                if (remainingInputLength >= 50)
                    splitIndex = 50;
                else
                    splitIndex = remainingInputLength;
            }
        }
        for (String s: chunks) System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```